# Aurelia binding an object in a custom element

Tags: binding, aurelia, custom-element

I have an object 'visit' that has several properties (e.g. visit1 = {id: 1, clientId: "0001", startTime: 1234567890, finishTime: 1234567899}). The visits are stored in the array 'shifts' that looks like shifts = [{id:1, visits: [visit1, ...]}, ...].

To display the data in the view, I use repeat.for:

```
<div repeat.for="shift of shifts">
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="visit of shift.visits">
      <visit-item visit.bind="visit" settings.bind="userSettings" selectors="selectors"></visit-item>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

'visit-item' is a custom element displaying the editable form for a single visit. Its view is:

```
<template>
<require from="./timepicker"></require>
<require from="../../converters/hour-format"></require>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <label>start</label><input timepicker class="form-control input-sm" id="startTime_${visit.id}" type="text" value.bind="visit.startTime | hourFormat">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <label>finish</label><input timepicker class="form-control input-sm" id="finishTime_${visit.id}" type="text" value.bind="visit.finishTime | hourFormat">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <label>client</label><select class="form-control input-sm" id="client_${visit.id}" value.bind="visit.clientId">
          <option repeat.for="option of selectors.client" model.bind="option.value" disabled.bind="option.disabled">${option.name}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

The view-model of visit-item:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class VisitItemCustomElement {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) visit;
  @bindable selectors;
  constructor()  {
  }
  bind()  {
  }
  visitChanged(newValue, oldValue)  {
    console.log("visit changed");
  }
}
```

I try to catch changes in the form of a visit by visitChanged() method, but visit-item's view-model doesn't call this method when I change values in the form. The same if I do valueChanged(). Is there any way to catch changes in the form with the described data design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `visit` isn't changing, it's the properties on `visit` that are changing. Since you only have a small number of properties you are binding to, you'd be best served by creating a bindable property on `visit-item` for each property you need to to be notified of changes.

Answer (score 1):

Very good @Ashley Grant.

I found a soultion when you want to observe one or some properties of a complex object. Tell me what you think of it.

```
import {bindable, bindingMode, BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';
@inject(BindingEngine)
export class VisitItemCustomElement {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) visit;
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
   this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }
  bind() { 
   this.subscription = this.bindingEngine
    .propertyObserver(this.visit, 'clientId') //e.g. subscribe to visit.clientId
    .subscribe(this.objectValueChanged); //subscribe to prop change
  }
  unbind() {
   this.subscription.dispose(); //otherwise you'll bind twice next time
  }
  visitChanged(newValue, oldValue)  {
    console.log(`visit changed from: ${oldValue} to:${newValue}`);
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.dispose();
    }
    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine
    .propertyObserver(this.visit, 'clientId')
    .subscribe(this.objectValueChanged); // subscribe again in case obj changes!
  };
  }
  objectValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(`objectValue changed from: ${oldValue} to:${newValue}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to catch changes when I include all properties displayed in the form as separate bound variables in the custom element. It looks bad since I have a lot of properties for a visit. If you happen to know a better solution, please let me know